# call a method when tab changed fragment

Tags: java, android

I build an Android App with 3 Tabs. Now I want to call a method, when I switch between this 3 fragments to update the view of the fragments. But the onResume() method doesn't work for that. Do you have any ideas how to call a method in a fragment, when switching to it ?
Thank you.

Comment: Use tab change listener. Call the method when tab changed.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I'm calling a static method in my fragment from the activity using the tab change listener.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using “import android.app.Fragment;”

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
fragment.<specific_function_name>();
```